# java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null' for Postgres database

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, datasource, postgresql-9.4

I am using JNDI datasource to connect to Postgres database. This is the code to of my ServletContextListener

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        try {
            // Obtain our environment naming context
            Context envCtx = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
            // initialize JNDI lookup parameters
            DataSource datasource = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/testdb");
            ManagerDao.getConn(datasource);
            ParticipantDao.getConn(datasource);
            EventDao.getConn(datasource);
            FacilitiesDao.getConn(datasource);              
        }
        catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

web.xml of App_path\WebContent\WEB-INF

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/testdb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/testdb"                  
                  auth="Container"
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource"             
                  username="postgres"
                  password="rules@123"
                  driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
                  url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/eventory"
                  maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
            />
```

But I am getting errors while the getConnection() methods are getting called.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2167)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2037)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543)
    at com.eventory.dao.FacilitiesDao.getConn(FacilitiesDao.java:26)
    at com.eventory.initDB.DBConnListener.contextInitialized(DBConnListener.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2151)
    ... 13 more
```

I have tried the following approaches:

1. Put the postgresql-42.1.4.jar in the tomcat lib folder.
2. Put the postgresql-42.1.4.jar in the App_Path\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib
3. Put the context.xml in the WebContent\META-INF folder
4. Put the context.xml in the tomcat\conf folder

Nothing seems to work. Is there any other approach that I missed? Please help.

Comment: Possible dublicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003999/cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-for-connect-url-null-hikaricp-tomcat8?rq=1

Comment: I did put context.xml in the META-INF folder

Comment: Please show the code of `FacilitiesDao` and one of the other 'dao' classes, it is rather curious that the other 'dao' classes before it work, but this one doesn't. That initialization itself sounds rather curious, you seem to be using singleton connections per dao (which is likely not thread-sade), instead of using a connection-per-request (workunit).

Comment: I started with a brand new environment. And it worked.Apparently, I had tried all the solutions and the tomcat ended up picking the wrong context.xml and postgres.jar. Not a problem with the DAO classes.